# How to set the font for an element to be Boostrap's default?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have a page on my website where I want to use a google font for the whole page except for the navbar. I want the navbar to keep the default bootstrap font. I set the body font to be my chosen google font. I am not exactly sure how I can change the navbar to be default bootstrap font.

```
      .nav-link{
                font-family: $font-family-base;
        }
```

I read on the bootstrap site that this is the variable that contains the font. I'm not sure if this is the proper usage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base font family refers to the following line:

`"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`

Thus, simply do the following:

```
.nav-link{
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```